# XAMPP or MAMP on Mac OS X 10.6.2 (Snow Leopard)

Tags: macos, xampp, mamp

I just bought a new MacBook Pro which comes with Snow Leopard 10.6.2 (Mac OS X 10.6.2). I am used to using XAMPP as my local development server on XP. Since Mac OS X is based on Unix, I was thinking on activating/installing all the necessary stuff as I would normally do on Linux. However, I am not quite ready to be playing around with the system at this point so having an external package would be a nice temporary solution I think.

The question is whether I should go with MAMP or XAMPP. Does anybody have any suggestions? The Pro and Cons I suppose. As far as I know, Mac OS X comes with Apache2 and PHP5. Would MAMP or XAMPP modify the existing Apache and PHP installation? Any comments on how I should proceed?

PS: Eventually I would use the default installation of Apache and PHP, and install a binary package of MySQL but time for development is an essence and I don't have time to familiarize myself with Mac OS X.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that anything related to servers should be posted on ServerFault. Or am I on the right place?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

XAMPP and MAMP are both quite similar. Neither touch your default OS X Apache/PHP! You can just try them both out and remove them afterwards by just deleting their folders. In the end they do exactly the same.

XAMPP gets updated more regularly and is generally more up to date. Also XAMPP has more extensions built-in.

On the other hand MAMP looks a little more mac-like and has a Dashboard Widget. But for a development system that doesn't count much. Unlike XAMPP, MAMP works without administrator privileges.

I went with XAMPP in the end because I needed the dba extension.

Comment: Thanks Wolax! I went with XAMPP. MAMP added the port number at the end of the url which is quite annoying to me. There might be a way around it but I just didn't have the inclination to play around.

I recompiled the existing php to the newest version and added mcrypt. Also installed MySQL.

Will remove XAMPP once everything is in place.

Answer (score 7):

after using both to develop some Wordpress sites locally on my mac I chose to go with MAMP.

The main problem (only problem actually) I had with XAMPP was that it had issues on OS X with file and folder permissions. 
doing something as simple as installing new Themes using the Wordpress online interface proved nearly impossible - in the end it required changing permissions on some of the Apache configuration files in the XAMPP dir. - even then it didn't entirely work.

I won't go into details - but suffice it to say I ended up thinking "why bother?" and just went back to MAMP.

that's just my experience mind you - but it is worth noting that it's so common that there are several sites/blog posts whose sole topic is how to fix this issue. just google "XAMPP Wordpress theme install problem" or something like that and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: I'm having the same issues with wordpress on XAMPP at the moment and came here to see if MAMP would solve my problems, thanks for your answer.

Comment: I had the same issues with folder permissions trying to publish a local REST web service to stream files, so now I will try MAMP

Answer (score 5):

I am a new developer and run 10.6.3 as well. I found MAMP Pro to be a better option than anything else. The personal web server that comes with Mac is really handy but maintaining the modules via macports was a pain.

Versus XAMP, MAMP Pro works really well cause it lets you tweak the modules as you wish and edit the myself/postfix/httpd configs easily. The two biggest reasons I love it is cause of the **easy dyndns integration**.

As for the port number, you can just edit it to 80 and not have to enter it manually each time when you browse to your local dev site.

Answer (score 4):

XAMPP has some awful issues on OS X with file permissions and it's been a complete nightmare. I strongly suggest that if you're going to be using Wordpress on the localhost, that you either know your stuff before installing XAMPP, or just go with something else that won't give you those problems; presumably MAMP, which is what I'm about to install.

Answer (score 1):

Personnally, i think that MAMP is easier to use. Especially if you want to define the folder where you want to run your local web sites. By default, in XAMPP your local web sites are in the APPLICATIONS folder and this is not a good solution. Moreless there is no password by default for MySQL in XAMPP. In MAMP it's really easy to change the directory that you want for your weblocal web sites. (just go to preferences). I tried to do that in XAMMP but there was access problems to httpd.conf of the apache web server.

Answer (score -2):

Neither if you do WordPress development. ServerPress has the most options in a dead simple user interface. http://www.serverpress.com/products/desktopserver/#compare