# XAMPP on iMac - will it adversely affect built in Apache, Perl, PHP

Tags: mysql, macos, apache, xampp

The issue of importance here is installing and using MySQL on my iMac.  To my knowledge, OS X (currently running OS X 10.5.8) has the Apache web server, Perl and PHP already installed (I've verified that by experiment).  It does not have MySQL installed however and I'd like to install it.

I stumbled upon a couple versions of the Apache, Perl, PHP, MySQL bundle known by various names such as MAMP, XAMP and XAMPP.  XAMPP seems to be the best of the bunch, but that's somewhat irrelevant to the discussion.  What I'd like to know is if I install, say XAMPP, will this affect the built-in Apache, Perl and PHP instances installed on the machine?  I don't want to mess those up in any way (i.e. will installing XAMPP change those installations?).  If it's a separate install, could there be conflicts of some sort between the built-in Apache and the one installed from XAMPP?

In case it isn't obvious, I know next to nothing about web servers or their configuration.

Answer (score 0):

See earlier SO question: [XAMPP or MAMP on Mac OS X 10.6.2 (Snow Leopard)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499154/xampp-or-mamp-on-mac-os-x-10-6-2-snow-leopard)

Read the docs: XAMPP - and Bitnami for that matter http://bitnami.org/stacks - don't change or impact current OS X installs of apache, php, etc.

XAMPP docs say that XAMPP "comes as a Mac OS X Installer package which contains all the necessary files and requires no dependencies."

Answer (score 0):

Regarding BitNami, I'd like to mention that if the installer detects any software running in the default port (for instance if you have your own Apache server running in your system), it will asked you to select a different port for BitNami and it will configure the new server using that port. You don't need to manually configure it after the installation, it is automatically done.