# Cookies work on Xamp on windows not on Mamp on Mac

Tags: php, windows, macos, cookies, mamp

I created a Website for an project. For the login i wanted to create cookies which are important for further steps.

```
     if( $row->Passwort ==  $pass && $row->Benutzername == $username ) 
     {
     setcookie("username",$username,time()+3600);
     setcookie("pass",$pass,time()+3600)  ;
     $_SESSION["Name"] = $row->Vorname; 
     echo body();
     }
```

the body() is the website displayed after.

My problem: i get the body() works however no cookie is created (on Mac [MAMP]), however if i run the exact same files on on Windows(XAMP) everything works perfectly fine. Please help me :/

If more questions please ask(sry bad english).

Comment: Why are you not running XAMPP on the Mac also (Much less hassle with possible settings differences)? also have you checked that your php.ini files match on the MAMPP and XAMPP

Comment: https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html diffences comparison: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499154/xampp-or-mamp-on-mac-os-x-10-6-2-snow-leopard